# Easiest way to type a hyphen on the Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard, symbols

I can type a minus (-), an en dash (–) and an em dash (—) easily, I often need hyphens (‐) though. Is there an easy keyboard shortcut? If not how else should I go about inserting hyphens into my prose? Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: when typing in a word processor, one can simply press the minus key rather than the real hyphen, to get a hyphen the software understands, right? (OpenOffice.org, for example, uses auto-correct to turn a hyphen into a minus, when applicable. Pressing the key that gets one a minus in a simple editor, gets me a hyphen in OpenOffice.org and the like.)

Comment: Yes, word processors usually replace a minus with the correct glyph for the context.

Comment: In fact, what you said was a minus (U+2D) is a [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus), which can represent many distinct characters but is usually rendered like a hyphen in a proportional-width font. A [minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) (−, U+2212) has the same width, height and thickness as a plus sign (e.g. −+−+−). If you want an exclusive [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), it is U+2010 (‐).

Answer (score 5):

It's a one-or-the-other solution, but you could use the built in text-replacement on OS X to replace a minus with a hyphen.

[image]

On the left I typed a minus, on the right I inserted a hyphen from the OS X Character Viewer. In theory it should replace all instances of a minus typed with a hyphen. As I said though, it's a one or the other solution. Alternatively, if you use the minus more than an en dash, just replace the en dash with a hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to create a custom keyboard layout (starting with the default Mac layout) which has the hyphen character in it.