# Mac: How do I remap the context menu key on my keyboard to the command key?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

I just got tho TRON gaming keyboard from razer. It's great: super sturdy and stuff.... But there is no command button on the right side... which is an issue for me, being a DVorak user, all of my shortcut keys become two handed.

But there is a context menu button inbetween alt and ctrl.

With KeyCodes from the mac app store, I've discovered that the key Is :

```
Key Down
Characters: 
Unicode:        16 / 0x10
Keys:       
Key Code:   110 / 0x6e
Modifiers:  256 / 0x100
```

So, I'd like to remap that key to the command key, which looks like this: 
(right command key)

```
Modifiers:  1048848 / 0x100110
```

Comment: Might be an answer here, see Kevin's answer...http://superuser.com/questions/267383/easiest-way-to-type-a-hyphen-on-the-mac

Comment: @Moab, but I need to know the Keycode for the command key in order for this to work. That program will work, if the command key has a key code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (formerly KeyRemap4Macbook), which contrary to it's name works with all keyboards on any mac, should do the trick. Really designed for these sort of things. *Especially* PC keyboards. Don't know if it has a predefined rule, but with the info you already have you may define your own.

MacOS Sierra requires Karabiner Elements & makes it impossible to remap the Eject-Key.

Answer (score 2):

In karabiner, you need to click "Change Key" then scroll down quite far to "For PC Users"  click Application Key to Command_L
[image: karabiner preferences window]

Comment: +1 for explicitly mentioning that 110 was the 'application' key

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MacOS Sierra, you will need Karabiner Elements, rather than Karabiner.  The window layout is somewhat different.
[image]